# Como ver os pesos no TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Eu fiz uma rede neural para estimar um valor final para mim, com base em 7 entradas. Possui apenas uma *hidden_layer* com 95 *perceptrons*. Eu gostaria de ver quais os pesos utilizados, após o treinamento. Já pesquisei para utilizar ferramentas como tf.Print() e tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, mas não consigo visualizar. Alguém saberia me ajudar com isto? A base do código que estou utilizando segue abaixo.

```
def norm(x, train_stats):
  return (x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']

def build_model(qtd, act, train_dataset):
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(qtd, activation=act, input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    #layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
  return model

def neural(dataset):
    # Split of train and test data
    train_dataset = dataset[:len(dataset) - 2]
    test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)

    # Data statistics
    train_stats = train_dataset.describe()
    train_stats.pop("Pta Taquara")
    train_stats = train_stats.transpose()

    train_labels = train_dataset.pop('Pta Taquara')
    test_labels = test_dataset.pop('Pta Taquara')

    normed_train_data = norm(train_dataset, train_stats)
    normed_test_data = norm(test_dataset, train_stats)

    EPOCHS = 1000

    # The patience parameter is the amount of epochs to check for improvement
    early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)

    #qtds = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]
    qtds = [95]

    #acts = [tf.nn.elu, tf.nn.relu, tf.nn.selu, tf.nn.sigmoid, tf.nn.tanh]
    acts = [tf.nn.tanh]

    for a in acts:
        for q in qtds:
            model = build_model(q, a, train_dataset)

            history = model.fit(normed_train_data, train_labels, epochs=EPOCHS,
                                validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0, callbacks=[early_stop, PrintDot()])

            hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)

            hist['epoch'] = history.epoch

            loss, mae, mse = model.evaluate(normed_test_data, test_labels, verbose=0)

            print("\nTesting set Mean Abs Error: {:5.2f} Pta Taquara".format(mae))

            test_predictions = model.predict(normed_test_data).flatten()
            print(test_predictions)
```

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no tensorboard?

Answer (score 1):

Duas informações para responder à sua pergunta:

1. Um objeto da classe *model* tem uma propriedade *layers*, que retorna uma lista com todas as camadas. Você pode usar para acessar as camadas individualmente. Por exemplo:

```
# acessa a primeira camada:
model.layers[0]

# percorre as camadas uma a uma e imprime o nome de cada camada no console:
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.name)
```

2. Um objeto da classe *layer* tem um método *get_weights()*, que retorna os pesos dessa camada. Assim, o que você quer verificar pode ser visto com o seguinte código:

```
# retorna os pesos e biases da primeira camada:
model.layers[0].get_weights()
```